# How do you test if a div has a certain css style in rspec/capybara?

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara

How do you test if a div tag has a certain css style?  I'm trying to test if it has `display:none;` or `display:block`.

I tried the following but its giving me an error:

```
it {should have_selector('signup_server_generic_errors', /display:\s*none/)}
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I'd recommend that instead of trying to locate the css style, you instead write your tests to find the *css class name*.

This way you can change the underlying css styling while keeping the class the same and your tests will still pass.

Searching for the underlying style is brittle. Styles change frequently. Basing your rspecs on finding specific style elements makes your tests more brittle -- they'll be more likely to fail when all you do is change a div's look and feel.

Basing your tests on finding css classes makes the tests more robust. It allows them to ensure your code is working correctly while not requiring you to change them when you change page styling.

In this case specifically, one option may be to define a css class named `.hidden` that sets `display:none;` on an element to hide it.

Like this:

css:

```
.hidden {
  display:none;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="hidden">HIDE ME!</div>
```

capybara:

```
it {should have_css('div.hidden') }
```

This capybara just looks for a div that has the `hidden` class -- you can make this matcher more sophisticated if you need.

But the main point is this -- attach styles to css class names, then tie your tests to the classes, not the styles.

Comment: In general this is good advice, with at least one exception: if you are trying to test whether an element is visible to the user. If that's the case, then testing for the presence of a CSS class is the wrong thing to do since that would be testing the implementation instead of the results and the point of testing is to allow you to change the implementation and ensure that you get the same results. If you are, in fact, testing whether an element is visible to the user, see luacassus's answer.

Comment: @toasterlovin - using good css classes can help with this, for example it's typical to see advanced front end devs use a class such as `.is-hidden { display: none; }` or similar which is then added using javascript or rendered on page load. Testing for the existence of this class would be pretty robust; I'd say the problem partly lies with front end bad practice (`$(elem).css('display', 'none');` for example)

Comment: I was trying to get at the difference between testing the implementation (does the element have a class which will make it hidden) and testing the actual thing you care about (is the element hidden). IMO, this is a critical aspect to writing useful tests. Testing the actual thing you care about means that you can refactor any and every thing about how you get to the result and your test will let you know if you've refactored correctly. If, on the other hand, you test the implementation, then the test becomes useless as soon as you change the implementation.

Answer (score 12):

You could use `has_css?` matcher. It can accept `:visible` options. For more details you can check docs: http://rdoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara/Node/Matchers#has_css%3F-instance_method

For example you can try:

```
it { should have_css('div.with-some-class', :visible => true) }
```

Comment: be careful with `:visible => true` - the result might not be accurate:
[http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Element#visible%3F-instance_method](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Element#visible%3F-instance_method)

Comment: Just want to point out the usage of the `:visible` option may be surprising if using `true` or `false`.  I have found using `visible: :visible` or `visible: :hidden` more clear.  [See details](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/commit/83742b008f0719082beb8f6703bc70ba956815fc#diff-da1771677e47ff6a7a70b8119e14102dR58) and [discussions on these symbol options](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/944)

Answer (score 9):

My way to ensure that element have a certain class:

```
let(:action_items) { page.find('div.action_items') }

it "action items displayed as buttons" do
  action_items.all(:css, 'a').each do |ai|
    expect(ai[:class]).to match(/btn/)
  end
end
```

or smthing like this

```
expect(ai[:style]).to match(/color: red/)
```

I found it here: http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara/Node/Element#%5B%5D-instance_method

Answer (score 2):

You can use Capybara's [assert_matches_style](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara%2FNode%2FMatchers:assert_matches_style), or the Rspec [HaveStyle](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara/RSpecMatchers/Matchers/MatchStyle) matcher (which is using assert_matches_style underneath):

When you use assert_matches_style directly, it's:

```
find(".element").assert_matches_style("font-size" => "46px")
```

I'm not too familiar with Rspec syntax, but it should be something like this:

```
it { should match_style("font-size" => "46px") }
```