# div show/hide UJS, remember state when form contains errors and render(action: :new) occurs

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ujs

Using 'form_for' to build Person for 'People' model. Here is UJS to show and hide div on checkbox click.

#### people.js

```
  window.onload = function() {
    $('#is_student_chkbx').click(function() {
      return $('#student_properties').toggle();
    });
    return true;
  };
```

#### genrated page people/new

```
...
<input id="is_student_chkbx" name="person[role_attributes][is_student]" type="checkbox" value="true" />

<div id='student_properties' style='display:none;'>
  <p>Test text</p>
</div>
...
```

#### people_controller.rb

```
class PeopleController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @person = Person.new
    @person.build_role
  end

  def create
    @person = Person.new(params[:person])
    ...
    @person.save ? redirect_to(person_path(@person)) : render(action: :new)
  end
end
```

But there is a problem. When form contains errors (like "Name can't be blank" because of validation in the model), `render(action: :new)` occurs but `'student_properties'` div is not visible even if `'is_student_chkbx'` is checked. So when I click `'is_student_chkbx'` again -> checkbox is not checked but `'student_properties'` div shows up.

So how to remember state of this div?

I tried to add `if ($('#is_student_chkbx').is(':checked')) {$('#student_properties').show();}` to `window.onload` but it didn't happend on `render(action: :new)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get it working, I used (thanks to rb512, who pointed my attention):

```
<div id='student_properties' style='display:<%= @person.role.is_student ? 'block' : 'none' %>;'>
```

Instead of:

```
<div id='student_properties' style='display:none;'>
```

But the better way is to [use CSS Class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11255963/1041467):

```
.hidden {
  display:none;
}
```

Then target string will look like:

```
<div class='your_other_class <%= 'hidden' unless @person.role.is_student %>' id='student_properties'>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your new action add the following:
**Update: missed the quotes**
`@person.role.is_student = false || params['is_student_chkbx']`

Comment: There is no need to do this - nested form works correctly. `is_student_chkbx` created using `fields_for`, that's why `name="person[role_attributes][is_student]"`