# Test view/DOM content RSpec ruby capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dom, rspec, capybara

I would like to know how test the DOM content in a view RSpec test, to know if the content exists I usually use match or have_content (match for HTML ids/classes), but here I would like to know if a div is visible or not (style display: none) and I don't know how do it.

What's the better way to check the DOM with RSpec?

I also talk about another developer and he says me that it was better to check the DOM and this kind of stuff in the feature test because the view was not good enough to do that, I would like to have another opinion about that.

Comment: if you want to see the actual content of the web_page you can add `save_and_open_page` before the assertion this works with `capybara`

Comment: Thanks, will be useful for something else,but I actually don't want to see it, I want to test it.

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11198882/how-do-you-test-if-a-div-has-a-certain-css-style-in-rspec-capybara)

Comment: Yeah, it's kinda what I need, but I still need to have another opinion too. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I test `DOM` element with `Rspec/Capybara`. I have `PageObject` class and include `Capybara::DSL` look example

in `spec/support/page_object.rb`:

```
class PageObject
  include Capybara::DSL

  def visit_page(page)
    visit(page)
    self
  end

  def have_field?(attributes)
    find_field(attributes).visible?
  end

  def have_link?(link)
    find(:xpath, "//a[@href='#{link}']").visible?
  end

  def save_and_open_page
    super
  end

  def login(model)
    fill_in 'email', with: model.email
    fill_in 'password', with: model.password
    click_on 'Submit'
  end

  def right_path?(path, page)
    visit_page(page) && current_path == path
  end
end
```

and `spec/views/event_spec.rb`:

```
require 'spec_helper'

feature 'test authozire page' do
  let(:login_page) { PageObject.new }
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

  scenario 'login page have field' do
    page = login_page.visit_page('/home/login')
    expect(page.have_field?('email')).to be_true
    expect(page.have_field?('password')).to be_true
    expect(page.have_link?('/users/auth/facebook')).to be_true
    expect(page.have_link?('/users/auth/vkontakte')).to be_true
  end

  scenario "user can login" do
    login_page.visit_page('/home/login').login(user)
    page = login_page.visit_page('/home/login')
    expect(page.have_link?('/search/events')).to be_true
    expect { page.have_link?('/search/users') }.to raise_error(Capybara::ElementNotFound)
    expect(login_page.visit_page('/user_profile')).to be_true
    expect(login_page.right_path?('/user_profile', '/user_profile')).to be_true
    expect(login_page.visit_page('/user_profile/edit')).to be_true
    expect(login_page.right_path?('/user_profile/edit', '/user_profile/edit')).to be_true
  end
end
```