# Test if a div has a certain css style in rspec/capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

Not a repeat of:
[How do you test if a div has a certain css style in rspec/capybara?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11198882/how-do-you-test-if-a-div-has-a-certain-css-style-in-rspec-capybara)

because those answers don't work for my case.

I have a webform with a preview; as you change certain parts of the web form, the previews update, and I want to check for this in my tests - so I really do need to check the styling that is applied to a div. Specifically, I'm updating the `background-color` of certain divs, and I want to check that this has happened.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which driver are you using?

Answer (score 10):

To my knowledge, Capybara does not have an API for getting the computed style of an element. However, since you are using Selenium-Webdriver, you can drop down to the Selenium element and use the `style` method.

For example, consider the following page which has a div element whose style is updated via javascript:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="red_div">
      background applied by javascript
    </div>
    <script>
      document.getElementById("red_div").style.background = "red";
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can get the computed style of the div by using the `style` (or `css_value`) method of the underlying Selenium element:

```
red_div = page.find(:css, '#red_div')
puts red_div.native.style('background-color')
#=> "rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)"
```

Note:

- `native` is the method to get the underlying Selenium element of a Capybara node.
- The value you get from `style` may vary across browsers. For example, for background-color, I believe IE would actually give you "red".

Answer (score 0):

you can use execute_script, hope this help.

```
 expect(page.execute_script("return window.getComputedStyle($('your-class-or-id')[0]).color").to eq('rgb(255, 255, 255)')
```